# (node.js module) sharp image processor keeps source file open, unable to unlink original after resize

Tags: node.js, typescript, unlink, sharp

I'm using [sharp](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/) to resize an uploaded image in a `Node.js` / `Express` application written in `Typescript`. After successful resizing, I'd like to delete the original file. For `png` and `gif` input images, the operation terminates successfully, I have the resized image and the original is deleted. For `jpg` and `tif` images, the resize is successful, however the `unlink` command fails with the following error:

> EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink '...'

as if the `sharp().resize()` would still keep the input file locked, even after the completion of the resize operation.

Here is the code to test the described behavior:

```
import { existsSync, unlinkSync } from "fs";
import { normalize, parse } from "path";

var argv = require("yargs").argv;
var sharp = require("sharp");
var appRoot = require("app-root-path") + "/";

let resizeTest = async function (filename: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        let nameParts = parse(filename);
        let source = appRoot + filename;
        let destination = appRoot + nameParts.name + "_resized" + nameParts.ext;
        let fileExists = await existsSync(source);
        if (!fileExists) {
            console.log("Input file not found. Exiting.");
            return false;
        }

        let resizeResult = await sharp(source)
            .resize(128, 128)
            .toFile(destination);
        console.log("Resize operation terminated: ", resizeResult);

        await unlinkSync(source);
        console.log("unlinkSync operation terminated.");

        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("An error occured during resizeTest execution: ", error.message);
        return false;
    }
}

if (argv._.length === 0) {
    console.log("Usage: node sharptest.js FILENAME");
} else {
    let resizeResult: Promise<boolean> = resizeTest(argv._[0]);
    resizeResult.then(result => console.log("Returning from execution with ", result));
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `sharp` work with promises? Can it be `await`ed on?

Comment: @robertklep yes according to the docs: http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-output/ The toFile() returns a promise when no callback is provided.

Comment: Generally, calling `unlink` on a file that's still open isn't a problem on Unix-type OS'es, which I assumed you were using because of you're use of forward slashes. If you're on Windows, check out [this issue](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/487), and its solution.

Comment: Perfect! That was it. Setting cache temporarily to false solved the issue. Add this please as an answer so I can upvote + accept it.

Comment: What version of sharp are you using? I'm using 0.17.1 with Typescript and I got the following error message Could not find a declaration file for module 'sharp'. '/code/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7016)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I initially was thrown by your use of forward slashes, assuming that you'd be using a Unix-type OS, where calling `unlink` of a file that is still open generally isn't a problem.

However, on Windows, I think that open files are usually protected from being deleted, and [this issue](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/487) describes a similar problem, and also a solution: internally, `sharp` maintains a cache of (open) files, which will block the original file from being deleted.

If you disable that cache, the problem should be fixed:

```
// add this at the top of your code
sharp.cache({ files : 0 });
```

Documented [here](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-utility#cache).

**EDIT**: as noted in some of the comments, the code above may not fix the problem. Instead, use this:

```
sharp.cache(false);
```

Comment: A bit of correction: sharp(...).cache is not a function. I had to call sharp.cache(...) and then separately the constructor sharp(...) with the chained commands.

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi thanks for the clarification, the entire `cache` function seems to be missing from the documentation so I had to guess how it would work. I'll update my answer :D

Comment: It's not trivial to find, cache is under utilities: http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-utility/#cache

Comment: Just a small note: on windows, `sharp.cache({ files : 0 });` didn't work for me, but `sharp.cache(false);` did.

Comment: @Cosmin Ababi Same here. `sharp.cache({ files : 0 });` didn't work for me.

Comment: Link rot has set in for this answer

Comment: @Luke you should have enough rep to edit the answer ;P in any case, I fixed the link, thanks for bringing it to my attention :D

Comment: I do but I don't have time to fix all of the links and find new ones

Answer (score 3):

internally, sharp maintains a cache of (open) files, which will block the original file from being deleted.

**`sharp.cache(false)`**;

above line add starting of your REST API